# How to extract the rows under a column using shell script

Tags: shell, string-formatting

I have following output of linux command brctl show. I would like to extract all the associated interfaces (as given in the interface column) and store it in some array. Can somebody suggest a way to achieve this?

```
root@XXXX:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled  interfaces
br-lan      7fff.00c0ca7e0288   no           eth0
                                             wlan1_1
                                             wlan1_1.sta1
```

I am missing the exact formatting for some reason. But the output of brctl show looks pretty much like above with the exception of a few spacings.

So I would like to store eth0,wlan1_1, w;an1_1.sta1 in some array if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` and `tail`. You may have to adjust the number:

```
brctl show | tail -n +2 | cut -c 36-
```

If the `tab` characters are converted to spaces in your output, you will need:

```
brctl show | tail -n +2 | cut -c 46-
```

---

**Bash script solution**

Note: I tested with a datafile of your data, but it should work with the `brctl show` output as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0
declare -a ifaces

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    [ $cnt -eq 0 ] && { ((cnt++)); continue; }
    ifaces+=( "${line//* /}" )
done <<<$(brctl show)

printf "%s\n" ${ifaces[@]}
```

**tested with `done <"$1"` as substitute:**

```
$ bash brctl.sh dat/brctl.txt
eth0
wlan1_1
wlan1_1.sta1
```

Comment: It gives me something to start with. Although reading the second line is still problematic and also there is difference in the number of characters in line 2, 3  and 4. For example [brctl show | tail -n +3 | cut -c 8-] works fine for line 3 and 4. But not so for line 2. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That is odd. I used `brctl show` here (had no interfaces) so I had to gauge off the 1st line. There the count was `36` to `interfaces` due to the `tab` chars separating the headings. I then copied your output to a text file and tested. The column you wanted then began at `46` due to spaces preceding all interfaces. If `brctl` is doing something strange like `mixing tabs and spaces` in the output, you will just have to play with it. The alternative is a `while read -r line` loop with tests on line to determine if there is text in chars `1->x` to do one thing, else do another.

Comment: Try the `bash script` solution I posted. As noted, I tested with your data in a text file, but the `brctl show` command should work the same due to the tests used.

Answer (score 0):

Shell script solution, more compatible and with less failure possibilities:

```
#!/bin/sh
BridgeMembers ()
{
    local TheBridge="$1"
    local CurrentLine=""
    local CurrentMac=""
    local CurrentNIC=""

    IFS="$(printf "\n\b")" ; for CurrentLine in $(brctl showmacs "$TheBridge" | tail -n +2) ; do unset IFS
        IsLocal="$(OneWord () { echo $3; }; OneWord $CurrentLine)"
        if [ "$IsLocal" = "yes" ] ; then
            CurrentMac="$(OneWord () { echo $2; }; OneWord $CurrentLine)"
            CurrentNic="$(env LANG=en ifconfig | grep -e $CurrentMac)"
            CurrentNic="$(OneWord () { echo $1; }; OneWord $CurrentNic)"
            echo "$CurrentNic"
        fi
    done
}

BridgeMembers "$1"
```

Note that with "brctl show" you didn't get same column widths all times.